# Attribute Error: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'active'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, openpyxl

I am new to both python programming and the raspberry pi environment and I need to do some project with it. As I was trying to run the sample code for the openpyxl library I found myself stuck in the error provided in the title, Attribute Error: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'active'
I tried to install some more packages to check if there are just missing libraries but none of them work

the code I am trying is below:

```
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A1'] = 42
    ws.append([1, 2, 3])
    import datetime
    ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

how can I get to run it? thanks in advance

Comment: What version of `openpyxl` are you running?  `import openpyxl; print(openpyxl.__version__)`

Comment: It's currently at 2.2.6, so the feature you're looking for might simply not exist in that version.  Can you `pip install openpyxl --upgrade` to bring it up to the most recent version?

Comment: thanks, it is working now. I thought my os has already some error or something as I tried to update openpyxl by `sudo apt-get python-openpyxl`

Comment: Excellent! I'll reiterate my comment as the answer-- if you could accept it, it might help people with similar issues in the future

Comment: openpyxl should always be installed using pip.

Comment: your code worked for me. If you are using python3 did you install with pip3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the version of the package you're running as it states that `active` is a property in the latest version of the documentation.

To discover your current version:

```
import openpyxl
print(openpyxl.__version__)
```

You should be able to upgrade your openpyxl version with `pip install openpyxl --upgrade` to get the latest version.

Comment: Should be pip install openpyxl --upgrade