# Workbook object has no attribute 'add_sheet' when using Workbook object from xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Not only am i fairly new to python, but this is my first post on this forum. I am learning how to integrate python and excel. I was able to get the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd, xlwt
import xlsxwriter
path = "C:/Users/Python/data/"
data = np.arange(1, 101).reshape((10,10))
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook(path + 'workbook.xlsx')
ws_1 = wb.add_sheet('first_sheet')
ws_2 = wb.add_sheet('second_sheet')
for c in range(data.shape[0]):
    for r in range(data.shape[1]):
        ws_1.write(r, c, data[c, r])
        ws_2.write(r, c, data[c, r])
wb.close()
```

to work on Jupyter Notebook and through the anaconda python shell, however when i run in Spyder, i get the following error message on the ipython console:

> runfile('C:/Users/Python/excel_integration1.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/Python') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Python/excel_integration1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Python')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 866, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 87, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/Python/excel_integration1.py", line 7, in 
>       ws_1 = wb.add_sheet('first_sheet')
>
> AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_sheet'

I look forward to all your help.

Comment: Always try googleing the error.  First result [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545454/attribute-error-workbook-object-has-no-attribute-active) searching `AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_sheet'` on google.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with either `anaconda`,  `jupyter-notebook`, nor `spyder`, so please don't tag it as such. Also, please come up with a better title. Your title should not be a request, it should be a short description of the problem. I'll go ahead and change it to something sensible. Note, this is not a "forum" but a Question and Answer site.

Comment: Er, your code doesn't seem to match your error message.  Your code says `ws_1 = wb.add_worksheet('first_sheet')` but the error message says `ws_1 = wb.add_sheet('first_sheet')`.  Could you check to see whether that's accurate?

Comment: yes the code should read `wb.add_sheet('first_sheet')`. i am editing the original post as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name in xlsxwriter, as shown in the xlsxwriter documentation, is `add_worksheet`.  You're using `add_sheet`.  I suspect you may have read examples from xlwt or a different library, because in xlwt you'd have

```
>>> import xlwt
>>> wb = xlwt.Workbook()
>>> wb.add_sheet("some name")
<xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet object at 0x7f6633b466d8>
```

but with xlsxwriter you have

```
>>> import xlsxwriter
>>> wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook()
>>> wb.add_sheet("won't work")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_sheet'
>>> wb.add_worksheet("will work")
<xlsxwriter.worksheet.Worksheet object at 0x7f6632e70320>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. thats exactly the issue.I appreciate all your help.